# TCP seq и ack номера

Tags: linux, c

Ситуация: самостоятельно собираю tcp-пакет и отсылаю. При посылке данных, система изменяет значения(которые я задавал явно) в полях seq и ack номеров на 1 или рандомное значение. Скажите, пожалуйста, с чем это связано?

---

Решение проблемы: для удобства wireshark и вправду интерпретирует поля seq и ack значениями, удобными для просмотра. На самом же деле они не изменяются.

Comment: Показали бы как его собираете, и главное, как его посылаете и как понимаете что эти поля изменились

Comment: @Mike, 
1) Присваиваю значения полям th_seq и th_ack так:
tcp->th_seq = htonl(10);
tcp->th_ack = htonl(1);
2) Отправляю через send(). 
3)Запускаю wireshark на целевой машине и ловлю пакет.
Все значения заголовков остались такими, какими их и задавал, имезняются только seq и ack

Comment: А как по-Вашему TCP информирует о доставке того или иного пакета? И вы вломились сходу в этот механизм.

Comment: Вы так и не сказали как вы отправляете пакет. то что send это понятно. но как вы сокет создавали, какой собственно тип сокета и т.п. лучше всего приведите код, которым вы это делаете, что бы можно было взять его и повторить ваши действия, что бы можно было воспроизвести эту проблему.

Comment: @Mike , вот ссылка: https://hello-site.ru/share/tcp_injection/

Comment: У меня seq и ack такие как задано. Правда контрольная сумма не верно рассчитана: https://pastebin.com/s5BbTzRh  Проверьте так же tcpdump на машине на которой формируете пакет. Может wireshark как то по другому показывает

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за помощь! Да, контрольная сумма была неверной. Что насчет seq, ack-полей: отписал в самом вопросе.

Comment: Не помещайте ответ в сам вопрос. Если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ — [это явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)